# MySQL error code 1215

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, database-schema

I have the following Schema: WilliamsSCW and I keep getting error: 1215 cannot add foreign key constrain for the Billing table.

Please help. What should I do?

```
Create database WilliamsSCW;

Create table WilliamsSCW.Login
(
UserName varchar(50) Not Null Primary Key,
Password varchar(50) Not Null);

Create table WilliamsSCW.Employee
(
employeeID int(8) Not Null Primary Key,
employeeFName varchar(25),
employeeLName varchar(25));

Create table WilliamsSCW.Customer
(
custID int(8) Not Null Primary Key,
custFName varchar(25),
custLName varchar(25),
custAddress varchar(30),
custCity varchar(30),
custState varchar(30),
custZip int(5),
custPhone BIGINT(10),
custEmail text);

Create table WilliamsWSC.Order1  #order is a reserved key word in MySQL and can't be used
(
orderID int(20) Not Null Primary Key,
orderDesc varchar(30),
orderType varchar(20),
orderCost int(10),
orderQuantity int(6),
orderContent text,
orderStatus varchar(10),
orderDate TimeStamp,
orderShipDate Date,
orderDeposit decimal(10,2),
mediaID BIGINT(20),
custID int(8),
employeeID int(8),
foreign key(mediaID) REFERENCES Media_Catalog(mediaID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
foreign key(custID) REFERENCES Customer(custID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
foreign key(employeeID) REFERENCES Employee(employeeID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE);

Create table WilliamsSCW.Billing
(
billingID int(8) Not Null Primary Key,
billingDate TimeStamp Not Null,
billDeposit decimal(10,2),
billAmt int(8),
employeeID int(8),
custID int(8),
orderID int(20),
foreign key(employeeID) REFERENCES Employee(employeeID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
foreign key(custID) REFERENCES Customer(custID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
foreign key(orderID) REFERENCES Order1(orderID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE);

Create table WilliamsSCW.Media_Catalog
(
mediaID BIGINT(20) Not Null Primary Key,
mediaCatalog varchar(30),
mediaPrice decimal(10,2),
mediaDesc text,
mediaJob varchar(20),
mediaAmntStock int(10));

Create table WilliamsSCW.Reason
(
onholdID int(20) Not Null Primary Key,
onholdDesc varchar(100),
orderID int(20),
foreign key (orderID) REFERENCES Order1(orderID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Thank you

Comment: Hi, why do you call a different database for the table "order1"?
WilliamsWSC and not WilliamsSCW

Comment: That was an error. I noticed that and fixed it to WilliamsSCW.    I'm still getting the error 1215

Comment: I figured out the problem, syntax issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the DDL for WilliamsSCW.Media_Catalog before Order1:

```
Create database WilliamsSCW;

Create table WilliamsSCW.Login
(
UserName varchar(50) Not Null Primary Key,
Password varchar(50) Not Null);

Create table WilliamsSCW.Employee
(
employeeID int(8) Not Null Primary Key,
employeeFName varchar(25),
employeeLName varchar(25));

Create table WilliamsSCW.Customer
(
custID int(8) Not Null Primary Key,
custFName varchar(25),
custLName varchar(25),
custAddress varchar(30),
custCity varchar(30),
custState varchar(30),
custZip int(5),
custPhone BIGINT(10),
custEmail text);

Create table WilliamsSCW.Media_Catalog
(
mediaID BIGINT(20) Not Null Primary Key,
mediaCatalog varchar(30),
mediaPrice decimal(10,2),
mediaDesc text,
mediaJob varchar(20),
mediaAmntStock int(10));

Create table WilliamsSCW.Order1  #order is a reserved key word in MySQL and can't be used
(
orderID int(20) Not Null Primary Key,
orderDesc varchar(30),
orderType varchar(20),
orderCost int(10),
orderQuantity int(6),
orderContent text,
orderStatus varchar(10),
orderDate TimeStamp,
orderShipDate Date,
orderDeposit decimal(10,2),
mediaID BIGINT(20),
custID int(8),
employeeID int(8),
foreign key(mediaID) REFERENCES Media_Catalog(mediaID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
foreign key(custID) REFERENCES Customer(custID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
foreign key(employeeID) REFERENCES Employee(employeeID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE);

Create table WilliamsSCW.Billing
(
billingID int(8) Not Null Primary Key,
billingDate TimeStamp Not Null,
billDeposit decimal(10,2),
billAmt int(8),
employeeID int(8),
custID int(8),
orderID int(20),
foreign key(employeeID) REFERENCES Employee(employeeID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
foreign key(custID) REFERENCES Customer(custID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
foreign key(orderID) REFERENCES Order1(orderID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE);

Create table WilliamsSCW.Reason
(
onholdID int(20) Not Null Primary Key,
onholdDesc varchar(100),
orderID int(20),
foreign key (orderID) REFERENCES Order1(orderID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE);
```